# Separated environment configurations into different folders and now Terraform wants to create all resources as if it doesn't know they exist

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Terraform v0.13.5
AzureRM v2.44.0

I use the AzureRM backend to store the tfstate file. My initial Terraform project had a master main.tf with some modules and I used workspaces to separate the different environments (dev/qa). This created the tfstate files in a single container and it would append the environment to the name of the tfstate file. I recently changed the file structure of my Terraform project so that each environment had its own folder instead, where I would change directory to that environment folder and run `terraform apply`

But now, Terraform wants to create all of the resources as if they don't exist even though my main.tf file is the same. So, it seems like I'm missing something here because now, I don't really need to use workspaces, but I need to use my existing tfstate files in azure so Terraform knows!

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I feel silly. I didn't realize that I never ran `terraform workspace select` when I went to the new folder. I guess what I should do is figure out how to do away with workspaces.

Comment: Basically, I ended up backing up the existing tfstate files that was in a good state. Updated the backend block so that the `key` value was unique. Then I used the terraform state push command to push the good tfstate file to Azure